# JavaScript alert with confirmation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, telerik

I have a JavaScript alert popup on my page. Problem I am having with it is that instead of waiting for the user to actually click the OK button, it simply does a redirect, something it ought to do AFTER the OK button has been clicked. Can anyone please help me tweak my code so as to get this working as it ought to please?

```
function f()
{

    ar ape =radalert('<div align=""center"" style=""font-weight: bold;""> OPEN BOX HERE</div>', 123, 200);
if(ape)window.location.href = "/Default.aspx";
Sys.Application.remove_load(f);
}

Sys.Application.add_load(f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `add_close` method to attach a callback function to know when the alert is closed:

```
var win = radalert('foo');
win.add_close(function () {
  alert('bar'); // This will be executed when the radalert is closed.
});
```

More info:

- [Telerik RadWindow Client-Side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window_programmingradwindowmethods.html)

Comment: Nice research on the return value of `radalert`.

Comment: +1 big time, in the time I gave it, I couldn't find the blasted reference docs.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using a JavaScript `alert` (in the sense of the built-in function), it looks like you're using something called `radalert` (from Telerik). That means it *can't* behave like a JavaScript `alert`, which brings script processing to a screeching halt while it's on-screen.

I know nothing about Telerik, but most of these alert replacements offer a callback you can pass that gets triggered when the alert is cleared. That's where you want your `window.location.href = ...` code.

Usually this looks something like this:

```
function blah() {

    niftyAlertThingy("Here's my message", {
        onOK: function() {
            window.location.href = "/Default.aspx";
            // etc.
        }
    });
}
```

That `blah` function returns *immediately*, with the alert still on the page; then the alert code calls your callback when the user clicks OK.

I'm sure the Telerik `radalert` has something similar...

Comment: Telerik does have something similar, but it's driven by the MS AJAX event subscription model, no callbacks. CMS covers it in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928804/javascript-alert-with-confirmation/1928896#1928896

Comment: Big +1 to CMS for finding the blasted docs. @Crescent Fresh: Surely that's a callback, though! ;-)

Comment: @T.J.: you know what I mean ;)

Comment: @CF: I didn't, but that's okay. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would think your code would need more explanation and possibly your code behind too (just the relevant code on how you handle "OK" Click). My experience with telerik is not good. I would suggest you to try jQuery UI. It gives you better control on how you can handle events and where.

Example( From [here](http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2009/03/12/Using-jQuery-UI-Dialogs-for-confirmation-windows.aspx))

```
$(function(){

    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    buttons : {
        "Yes" : function() {              
            $(this).dialog("close");
            eval($("#<%= hdnBtnPostback.ClientID %>").val());
        },
        "No" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Maybe": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            //what should we do when "Maybe" is clicked?
        }        
    }
    });
});
```